# Elements move when resize page

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Have positined elements with CSS & Tailwind CSS.

The elements move though whenever I move the page vertically. The 'fixed' property seems to be the culprit but I am unsure how to get the elements lower on the page without the fixed property.

Code so far:

```
  .swipeButtonsXS {
    bottom: 11vh;
    gap: 15px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .swipeButtonsSM {
    bottom: 11vh;
    gap: 15px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .swipeButtonsMD {
    bottom: 11vh;
    gap: 15px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .swipeButtonsLG {
    bottom: 4vh;
    gap: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  .swipeButtonsXL {
    bottom: 31vh;
    gap: 15px;
  }
}
```

```
import { FaCheck } from "react-icons/fa";
import "./DatingMainButtons.css";
function DatingMainButtons() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="fixed w-full flex justify-center swipeButtonsXL swipeButtonsLG swipeButtonsMD swipeButtonsSM swipeButtonsXS ">
        <FaTimes className="xl:w-10 xl:h-10 lg:w-7 lg:h-7 md:w-7 md:h-7 sm:w-6 sm:h-6  xs:w-6 xs:h-6  border border-gray-200  rounded-full bg-white text-gray-300 transition duration-500 ease-in-out  transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110" />
        <FaCheck className="xl:w-10 xl:h-10 lg:w-7 lg:h-7 md:w-7 md:h-7 sm:w-6 sm:h-6  xs:w-6 xs:h-6  border border-gray-200  rounded-full bg-white text-gray-600 transition duration-500 ease-in-out  transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110" />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need a parent div with `w-full`, `h-screen`, `overflow-auto` and `relative` as tailwind classes. You put all you page content in this div, including the button component. Simplified example:

```
<div class="w-full h-full overflow-auto relative">
    <!-- Full width and height container -->
    <div>...Scrollable main content...</div>
    <div class="fixed w-full bottom-4 gap-4 flex justify-center">
        <!-- Fixed button row -->
        <FaTimes class="..."></FaTimes>
        <FaCheck class="..."></FaCheck>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am unsure why but this doesn't solve the issue - this is a tricky CSS problem this!

Appreciate the attempt a ton though

Comment: Well that's unfortunate to hear. I'm sure there is a lot of other code involved which influences the behavior :-) I think the parent div with the relative class should be the 'highest' div on the page. So maybe that needs to be in another parent component.

Comment: Is this the behavior that you are after? https://play.tailwindcss.com/kh0Rel3dmP

Comment: Hi, not exactly, buttons essentially move up the page rather than staying in place - very annoying hahaha

Comment: Well I don't know what is happening, but in my browser the buttons in the tailwind play example stay at the bottom of the page, while the rest is scrolling...